# getting error ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: sql, oracle

i have used code `update football_team set DOB='1991-06-07' where id=1;`  but it is giving error

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: Can you add the table description please? Is `DOB` a date type?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
update football_team 
set DOB=TO_DATE('1991-06-07', 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
where id=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because date FormatString not correct
try following

```
update football_team set DOB=TO_DATE('1991/06/07','yyyy/mm/dd') where id=1;
```

or your custom format